# Site workflow to check library status in Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

Is there a way to create Site workflow on site collection which can loop all subsites and get items from Common library where status = complete and consolidate and send email

Sending email on Particular status can be done , just want to check its possible to loop all subsites and get item from Library in designer Workflow

Answer (score 0):

Looping Through Content in a SharePoint 2013 Site Workflow for your reference:

https://sympmarc.com/series/looping-through-content-in-a-sharepoint-2013-site-workflow/

Comment: Thanks, but however it's not a full article , only issue I am having how to loop susbites and lists ?